# remove space between two vbox

Tags: spacing

How can I remove space betwwen two vbox
minimal code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=.5cm,right=.5cm,top=.5cm,bottom=.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=.5\linewidth Hi}
    \setbox1=\vbox{\hsize=.5\linewidth everyone}
    \setbox2=\hbox{\vrule\box0\vrule\box1\vrule}
    \setbox3=\vbox{\hrule\box2\hrule}
    \copy3\copy3
\end{document}
```

output
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove the interline glue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=.5cm,right=.5cm,top=.5cm,bottom=.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=.5\linewidth Hi}
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=.5\linewidth everyone}
\setbox4=\hbox{\vrule\box0\vrule\box2\vrule}
\setbox6=\vbox{\hrule\box4\hrule}
\copy6\nointerlineskip\kern-0.4pt\copy6

\end{document}
```

I also added a kern to superimpose the two rules and changed the register numbers; as a general rule, for this purpose only even numbered registers should be used.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The space between the `\vbox`es is controlled by the `\baselineskip` and `\lineskip` glues. If you make them box zero, the boxes will be glued together.

I enclosed the setting of the skips in a group to prevent it from affecting the rest of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=.5cm,right=.5cm,top=.5cm,bottom=.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=.5\linewidth Hi}
    \setbox1=\vbox{\hsize=.5\linewidth everyone}
    \setbox2=\hbox{\vrule\box0\vrule\box1\vrule}
    \setbox3=\vbox{\hrule\box2\hrule}
    {\baselineskip=0pt
    \lineskip=0pt
    \copy3\copy3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once well clarified by others how to deal with interline skips, maybe for  newbies is worth to note that the same result can be obtained much easier with a simple table, without having to worry about line skips (... well, really a better result, as the central horizontal line is only typed once).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{Hi}X|>{everyone}X|}
\hline&\\\hline&\\\hline\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: I know about tabular environment. this minimal code was just for reveal my problem not real used code. Thanks for your attention and excuse me for my bad English.